# Android: download/create and share file issue causing too many crashes mostly on android 10 (Android Q)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-10.0

I have an android application which allows user to create, download, and share content like images, videos, etc.

Recently I have provided updated with API version 29 and it is causing too many crashes on my app while downloading and sharing files. Most of them are like

> *Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null
> object reference*
>
> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a
> null object reference

There are a total of two class that I use to download and share files one is written in java and other is written in kotlin, so basically I get URL of the file to pass it to my downloader task and then share URI/bitmap after download gets complete to my ShareUtil class from there I share files.

Below is code where I start download task:

```
                if (!UserStatus.isStoragePermissionGranted(DetailImageNew.this)) {
                    checkPermission();
                } else if (!UserStatus.isNetworkConnected(DetailImageNew.this)) {
                    Toasty.warning(DetailImageNew.this.getApplicationContext(), DetailImageNew.this.getResources().getString(R.string.downloadingoffline), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                    mainImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    Bitmap scaledBitmap = mainImage.getDrawingCache();

                    other = 1;
                    ShareUtil.shareImage(scaledBitmap, DetailImageNew.this, catshare);
                } else {

                    if (!maindownloading) {
                        maindownloading = true;
                        MyDownloadTask.DownloadListener downloadListener = new MyDownloadTask.DownloadListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void status(boolean downloading) {
                                ((Activity) DetailImageNew.this).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (downloading) {
                                            relative_layout_progress_fragement_video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        } else {
                                            relative_layout_progress_fragement_video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void downlodedFile(@NotNull File file) {
                                sharefile = file;
                                DetailImageNew.this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(sharefile)));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDownloadComplete(boolean download, int pos) {
                                maindownloading = false;
                                other = 1;
                                ShareUtil.share(DetailImageNew.this, sharefile,catshare);
                                Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.images_downloaded), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void downloadProgress(int status) {

                                ((Activity) DetailImageNew.this).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        progress_bar_fragement_video.setProgress(status);
                                        text_view_progress_fragement_video.setText(DetailImageNew.this.getResources().getString(R.string.downloading) + " " + status + " %");
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        };
                        String basename = FilenameUtils.getName(statusRead.getStatus());
                        new MyDownloadTask(DetailImageNew.this, statusRead.getStatus(), basename, 1, downloadListener).execute(true);

                    } else {
                        Toasty.warning(DetailImageNew.this.getApplicationContext(), DetailImageNew.this.getResources().getString(R.string.downloadingoffline), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

                    }
                }
```

so here I share the file using MyDownloadTask kotlin class, code of MyDownloadTask as below:

```
class MyDownloadTask ( @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") val context: Context,
val yourUrl: String,
val fileName: String,
val position: Int,
val listener: DownloadListener
) : AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Boolean>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg booleans: Boolean?): Boolean {

        var lenghtOfFile: Long = 0
        var status = 0
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(yourUrl)
                .build()
        var response: Response? = null


        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute()

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val inputStream: InputStream
        try {
            lenghtOfFile = response!!.body!!.contentLength()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }

        try {
            assert(response!!.body != null)
            inputStream = response!!.body!!.byteStream()

            val buff = ByteArray(1024 * 4)
            var downloaded: Long = 0


            val folder =
                    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/APPNAME/")
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir()
            }

            val documentFile = File("$folder/$fileName")
            documentFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
            try {
                documentFile.createNewFile()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            var output: OutputStream? = null
            try {
                output = FileOutputStream(documentFile, false)
            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            while (true) {

                val readed = inputStream.read(buff)

                if (readed == -1) {
                    break
                }
                if (isCancelled) {
                    break
                }
                downloaded += readed.toLong()
                status = (downloaded * 100 / lenghtOfFile).toInt()

                listener.downloadProgress(status)

                output!!.write(buff, 0, readed)

            }

            output!!.flush()
            val file: File
            listener.downlodedFile(documentFile)
            listener.status(false)
            output.close()
            return true

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return false
        }

    }


    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        listener.status(true)

    }


    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Void) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(objects: Boolean?) {
        super.onPostExecute(objects)
        if (objects!!) {
            listener.onDownloadComplete(true, position)
        } else {
            listener.onDownloadComplete(false, position)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(aBoolean: Boolean?) {
        super.onCancelled(aBoolean)
        val folder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/APPNAME/")
        val documentFile = File("$folder/$fileName")
        documentFile.delete()
    }

    override fun onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled()


    }


  public  interface DownloadListener {
        fun onDownloadComplete(download: Boolean, pos: Int)
        fun downloadProgress(status: Int)
        fun downlodedFile(file: File)
        fun status(state: Boolean)
    }
}
```

After file download gets complete I share the file to my ShareUtil Class as:

```
   public static void share(Context context, File file, String catshare) {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    shareImage(image, context, catshare);
}



 public static String shareImage(Bitmap image, Context mContext, String shareurl) {
    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    image = overlayCustom(image, mContext, 0, 0);

    String savedImagePath = null;
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    String imageFileName = "EHS_" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/APPNAME");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.close();
            bmpUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, imageFile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "" + "" +
                "\n\n" + UserStatus.getConfig(mContext).getSharestring() + " :- " + shareurl);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "APPNAME"));
    }
    return savedImagePath;
}




 public static Bitmap overlayCustom(Bitmap bmp1, Context context, int ci, int what) {
    String appname = "";
    if (what == 0)
        appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.kanmani);
    else
        appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.kanmani);
    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_white);
    bmp1 = overlayBitmapToBottom(bmp1, picture, context, bmp1.getConfig(), appname);
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

for sharing file without internet code is like:

```
  public static String shareImage(Bitmap image, Context mContext, String shareurl) {
    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    image = overlayCustom(image, mContext, 0, 0);

    String savedImagePath = null;
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    String imageFileName = "EHS_" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/APPNAME");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.close();
            bmpUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, imageFile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "" + "" +
                "\n\n" + UserStatus.getConfig(mContext).getSharestring() + " :- " + shareurl);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "APPNAME"));
    }
    return savedImagePath;
}
```

I have already followeds guideline for Android Q for file sharing like:

> Added line for requestLegacyExternalStorage in the manifest file.
> Using FileProvider

The same error is also happening on android versions less than 10 (Q) many times.

While testing I never got these errors at all but anyhow these errors coming to production and I am not able to reproduce them at my end.

Please help me as these errors are causing too many crashes in my production release.

Comment: If pointers are `null` then dont use them. Check for null before use and if null display a toast to inform the user and stop.

Comment: `NullPointerException`. You should also indicate us which pointers are null.

Comment: `folder.mkdir()` You are not checking the return value.

Comment: `success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {` Here you do. What is better you think?

Comment: `documentFile.parentFile.mkdirs()` Why you need that yet another time?

Comment: `catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }` You have several of those catch blocks which is good. But if there is a catch then you continue as if the catch did not happen. Which is bad.

Comment: `NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference` Where is the code where you use uri.toString()?

Comment: `for sharing file without internet code is like:` You are sharing a bitmap.